# add pull2refresh to tabs in codenameone

Tags: codenameone, pull-to-refresh

i have added the following codes for pull2refresh but the run method is not called. I have tested for form and its ok for form. How to make it workable for tabs so that I can update all tab at once . and I have pull2refresh of form for whole for refresh.

```
findTabs1(f).getContentPane().addPullToRefresh(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           // throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
          //
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Tab doesn't have contentPane but TabbedPane.

To add pullToRefresh to a tab, you should add it to the container you added to the tab and it must be scrollable-Y.

Instead of `findTabs1(f).getContentPane().addPullToRefresh` do `findMyContainerInsideTab().addPullToRefresh`

Comment: Hi Diamond ,
findMyContainerInsideTab().addPullToRefresh works well and
 I want to add pull2refresh in single tabs instead of adding in each tab.
And I did not find  findTabs1(f).getTabbedPane(); method

Comment: I don't understand your comment, you want to add what?

Comment: I have edited it
Hi Diamond ,
findMyContainerInsideTab().addPullToRefresh works well and
 I want to add pull2refresh in single tabs instead of adding in each tab.
And I did not find  findTabs1(f).getTabbedPane(); method

Comment: Because tab itself is not scrollable, so you can't. you can only add it to individual container inside the tab.

Comment: ok 
I add the listener to each tab and it works well 
is there anyelse solution with single listener except adding listener to form?

Comment: Not really, but you can declare your listener as a variable and apply it to both. You can post this as a new question with your code snippet and I will answer with a coding example